# istream_iterator eos

Tags: c++, iterator, cin

Is there any way to end writing to the console, terminate the writing and continue program, if you code the input as

```
std::istream_iterator<std::string> ii(std::cin);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> eos;
std::for_each(ii,eos,record);
```

I wonder if you can put something in the console that will terminate the input process if it is coded this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send an [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) to the standard input stream from the terminal by pressing CTRL-Z on Windows or CTRL-D on Linux.

Comment: I was using it in some other cases, but I was just not aware of the fact that this is actually EOF. or the way to send EOF  : D